# send an object via post

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I want to make a form in which I can update my entity in my REST application. For example I have a User entity whith username and realname fields.

Do I need in my request method do something like this

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/user/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateHouse(@RequestBody String username, @RequestBody String realname, Model model)
```

??

I would prefer to make something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/house/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateHouse(@RequestBody User user, Model model)
```

I mean that I want to send an object not every field. If i`ll have 20 fields in my entity I would have to add 20 params to my method. Thats not to fancy.

I`m using spring form tag

------- UPDATE

thanks for response. below diffrent entity but real case scenario that i`m trying to start

html code

```
<c:url var="houseUpdateLink" value="/admin/house/update" />
<form:form method="post" commandName="house" action="${houseUpdateLink}">
    <form:input path="house.title" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form:form>
```

controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/house/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateHouse(@RequestBody House house, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("step", 3);

    logger.info("test: " + house.getTitle());
    return "houseAdmin";
}
```

and i receive

```
HTTP Status 415 -

type Status report

message

description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format     not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().
```

Comment: yes and it failed so I wanted to ask is it even possible

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The 1st approach is bad, the 2nd one is good. Try rephrasing your question to describe what happens when you try, including an example HTML form that triggers the post.

Comment: If you find an answer to your own question (which is perfectly OK), then you should post it as an answer, not add it to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `@RequestBody` here. Spring will automatically bind the form fields to the `House` class without it, i.e.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/house/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateHouse(House house, Model model) {
```

Comment: true that. it`s shorter and does the same so it`s better solution. thanks for help :)

Comment: True, in the case of HTML Form content only. What if i need to post the data in form of JSON?? Will it work then??

Answer (score -1):

In the Spring form tags, you can probably do `user.username`, and pass the `User` object as a param.

Comment: no I can`t do that cause he would look for property user which is wrong and gives an error